# How does $.ajax success scope work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

```
var myXML;
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  url:'http://localhost:8080/someCGIhere/',
  datatype:'xml',
  success: function(xml){
    console.log('Success!');
    myXML = $(xml).find('SomeThing').text();
    //1) Prints out the myXML value        
    console.log("myXML = " +myXML);
  }
});

//2) Prints out undefined
console.log('Result = '+myXML);
```

How come the response is not stored outside of success scope, considering it is assigning the value to a variable declared outside of its scope?

Comment: `$.ajax`make an async request so `//2` is executed before `//1` .You should be able to see `Result = undefined` before `Success!` in the console

Comment: I do see it in the console, now I understand! in my mind javascript had to wait for the call to finish before it could proceed sequentially in the code, thank you! @Hacketo

Comment: Sorry Hacketo, I did not see your comment before I answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second console.log gets executed before the first one in the success function, since ajax is an asynchronous process. You either need to use a callback function to make sure the second console.log gets executed after the ajax call or you can use [promises](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what your code is doing.

1. declare the variable `myXML` (=null)
2. **start** the $.ajax request (and declare what to do if it - eventually, at some point in the future - finishes successfully)
3. log the content of `myXML`

Note that unless the `success` callback is called before point 3. (which is *extremely* unlikely), `myXML` will still be `null` at that point.

In other words, when the callback is called, `myXML` shall be updated. Before that, it is what you declared it to be in point 1, i.e. `null`. The code does exactly what you asked it to do, but it's something else than what you wanted.